# How to install gnomebaker?

Tags: installation

How to install gnome baker?After downloading the software-files,I can't find the executed file or how to navigate to launch to install it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and Run Following Commands

Add Gnomebaker repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnomebaker/stable
```

Install gnomebaker

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnomebaker
```

Comment: Doesn't work on 16.04

Comment: does not work for me (December 30, 2023)

Answer (score 1):

INSTALL FOR Ubuntu Versions 12.04 & 13.04.

Just open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnomebaker/stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gnomebaker
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> when asked to. You should be set.

Comment: Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease [5,931 B] 
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: This is not working? How can I proceed?

Comment: Gnomebaker project is closed longtime ago and not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with `apt-get` command. Type `sudo apt-get install gnomebaker` in terminal.

Comment: Result.....        Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnomebaker

Comment: How can I proceed?