# how to download gnomebaker

Tags: software-installation

How to download gnomebaker?

I followed instructions here [1]

I type

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnomebaker/stable

The result is

Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
stable ppa repository for gnomebaker
For all those that hate brasero and badly burned cd/dvd media.
More info: [https://launchpad.net/~gnomebaker/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnomebaker/+archive/ubuntu/stable)
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gnomebaker-ubuntu-stable.gpg with fingerprint 5AF257AA4E391ECE0E181CBAEC2962268472BD8C
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease [5,931 B]
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

**Question**

Considering these errors, how can I download gnomebaker?

**Updates**

*Dec 30, 2023 19:07 PM EST*

I went to "What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?"

there I found only things about something called trust media. I have no idea what that is. It is a program for all PPA, or is it a PPA. By the way, what is a PPA.  As far as I can tell, if the PPA owner does not update for new distributions of Ubunto, then one is just out of luck. So, in some sense the link helps. It helps me realize to leave this be and find a new solution altogether.

**Bibliography**

[1] [How to install gnomebaker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220865/how-to-install-gnomebaker)

Comment: A quick look and I can see that PPA doesn't support any Ubuntu release from 2013 onwards; did you check?   https://launchpad.net/~gnomebaker/+archive/ubuntu/stable   *taken from your provided details*

Comment: When you say, "did you check you launchapad..."  do you mean to say, "if you were to check launchpad you would see that you are not compatible to download. So give up." Or did you mean, "If you check launchpad you can find a work around". To answer your question. I just opened that link that you sent me about lauchpad. No idea what to do from there .

Comment: @guiverc.  I went to the link about PPA. Nope it does not answer my question. I struggle to understand how to resolve the matter. Thanks, Michael

Comment: The app was for GNOME 2 (GTK2), modern GNOME is now at GNOME 4, with 3 in *maintenance* support only, and 2 having been *deprecated* for a long time... The package was dropped long ago upstream (https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gnomebaker) as per https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=590890  I'd not recommend trying to get it operating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app was for GNOME 2 (GTK2), modern GNOME is now at GNOME 4, with 3 in *maintenance* support only, and 2 having been *deprecated* for a long time...

The package was dropped long ago upstream (https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gnomebaker) as per https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=590890

> Please remove gnomebaker. It's unmaintained for a long time, dead
> upstream, doesn't work with current kernels (see #402777) and
> replacements exist (e.g. Brasero, XFBurn or K3b). Looking at the BTS
> it seems fairly buggy anyway.

I'd not recommend trying to get it operating, but use a modern and mostly importantly *maintained* alternative.

Comment: Hi. I like your answer. When I try Bracero, Bracero keeps crashing continuously. Do you have any suggesions for a maintained alternative?

Comment: At Lubuntu we provided `k3b` (Lubuntu uses LXQt thus a Qt5 desktop) until [we dropped it](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/dropping-trojita-k3b-fcitx-from-lubuntu-jammy-22-04-seed/3044).  Personally I do like `xfburn` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/xfburn)  but be aware that most burners are getting OLD & fail often.  I've had 3 burners fail over my last 5 writes (*bad stat I know, but I'm replacing it with another recycled drive from a pile, and many burners today are old & can fail during writing*) so confirm you have good hardware I'll suggest.

Comment: I have no idea if the actual burner is good. However, when I try to read DVD, the external CD reads just fine. Also, I never his the write button with Bracero. After simply putting folders into the software drop box area, the Bracero closes.